I need help resolving a memory allocation error occurring during image search in a WinForms application
This is a game macro I created for the first time using C# WinForms. All actions were performed as intended, but the following error message is displayed in the UseImageSearch() function:
Error occurred during image search: Failed to allocate 3582272 bytes
Error occurred during image search: Failed to allocate 3582272 bytes
Error occurred during image search: Failed to allocate 3582272 bytes

Since this is the first code I've written, I'm not sure where it went wrong. I'm looking for a prince who can improve the code.
Below is the entire code.
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using OpenCvSharp;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CookieRunMacro
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        IntPtr bsW;
        IntPtr bstW;
        private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
        private bool isRunning = false;
        private const int MaxLines = 20;
        int count = 0;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")] // Find window
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName); 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] // Find child window
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hWnd1, IntPtr hWnd2, string lpsz1, string lpsz2);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] // Show window
        public static extern void SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] // Restore window
        public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] // Change window position
        public static extern int SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcblt, int nFlags);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] // Send message to window
        public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        private const uint WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

        public static IntPtr BlueStackFind(string window)
        {
            IntPtr hw1 = FindWindow("Qt5154QWindowOwnDCIcon", "BlueStacks App Player");
            IntPtr hw2 = FindWindowEx(hw1, IntPtr.Zero, null, "HD-Player");
            return hw2;
        }

        private void AddText(string text)
        {
            // Add line to text box
            logTextBox.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);

            // If lines in text box exceed maximum lines
            if (logTextBox.Lines.Length > MaxLines)
            {
                // Remove old lines
                logTextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, logTextBox.Lines.Skip(logTextBox.Lines.Length - MaxLines));
            }
        }

        public async Task RangeClick(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
        {
            if (!isRunning)
                return;
            int x = rand.Next(startX, endX + 1);
            int y = rand.Next(startY, endY + 1);
            IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)((y << 16) | (x & 0xFFFF));
            PostMessage(bstW, 0x0006, (IntPtr)1, lParam);
            PostMessage(bstW, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)0x0001, lParam);
            await Task.Delay(rand.Next(30, 80));
            PostMessage(bstW, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, lParam);
            AddText("Click(x, y): " + x + ", " + y);
        }

        public string[] ResourcesLoad(string folderPath)
        {
            string[] imgPaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.png");
            return imgPaths;
        }

        public string[] UseImageSearch(string imgPath, double threshold = 0.98f)
        {
            if (!isRunning)
                return null;

            Graphics gdata = Graphics.FromHwnd(bstW);
            Rectangle rect = Rectangle.Round(gdata.VisibleClipBounds);
            Bitmap screenBitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);

            try
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screenBitmap))
                {
                    IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
                    PrintWindow(bstW, hdc, 0x2);
                    g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
                }
                using (Mat screenMat = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(screenBitmap).CvtColor(ColorConversionCodes.BGRA2GRAY))
                using (Mat findMat = Cv2.ImRead(imgPath, ImreadModes.Grayscale))
                using (Mat result = new Mat())
                {
                    // Perform template matching
                    Cv2.MatchTemplate(screenMat, findMat, result, TemplateMatchModes.CCoeffNormed);

                    // Find max value in result matrix
                    Cv2.MinMaxLoc(result, out _, out double maxVal, out _, out OpenCvSharp.Point maxLoc);

                    // return
                    // 0: image similarity
                    // 1,2: image coordinates (x, y)
                    // 3,4: image dimensions (width, height)
                    if (maxVal >= threshold)
                    {
                        return new string[] { maxVal.ToString(), maxLoc.X.ToString(), maxLoc.Y.ToString(), findMat.Width.ToString(), findMat.Height.ToString() };
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AddText("Error occurred during image search: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                screenBitmap.Dispose();
            }

            return null;
        }

        public async Task MacroLogicAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    bool isDead = false;
                    do
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                        string[] imgPaths = ResourcesLoad("./Resources/");
                        foreach (string imgPath in imgPaths)
                        {
                            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested || !isRunning)
                                return;
                            String[] data = UseImageSearch(imgPath);
                            if (data != null)
                            {
                                AddText("\"" + imgPath + "\" Image recognition successful");
                                AddText("Found image similarity: " + data[0]);
                                int x, y, w, h;
                                int.TryParse(data[1], out x); // x-coordinate
                                int.TryParse(data[2], out y); // y-coordinate
                                int.TryParse(data[3], out w); // width
                                int.TryParse(data[4], out h); // height
                                await RangeClick(x, y, x + w, y + h);
                                if (imgPath == "./Resources/DeathConfirmation.PNG")
                                {
                                    isDead = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } while (!isDead);

                    count += 1;
                    countText.Text = "Repetitions: " + count.ToString() + " times";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AddText("Error occurred during macro execution: " + ex.Message);
                isRunning = false;
                startButton.Invoke(new Action(() => startButton.Enabled = true));
                stopButton.Invoke(new Action(() => stopButton.Enabled = false));
            }
        }        

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startButton.Enabled = false;
            stopButton.Enabled = true;
            AddText("Starting macro.");

            if ((IntPtr)BlueStackFind("BlueStacks App Player") == (IntPtr)0)
            {
                startButton.Enabled = true;
                stopButton.Enabled = false;
                AddText("Cannot find handle.");
                AddText("Stopping macro.");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                AddText("BlueStack handle detected.");
            }

            bsW = FindWindow(null, "BlueStacks App Player");
            bstW = BlueStackFind("BlueStacks App Player");
            SetForegroundWindow(bsW);
            ShowWindow(bsW, 5);
            SetWindowPos(bsW, 0, 0, 0, 925, 535, 0x0040 | 0x0010);
            SetWindowPos(bsW, 0, 0, 0, 925, 535, 0x0040 | 0x0001);

            if (!isRunning)
            {
                isRunning = true;
                cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                await Task.Run(() => MacroLogicAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token));
                // await MacroLogicAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token));
            }
        }

        private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cancellationTokenSource != null)
            {
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                cancellationTokenSource = null;
            }
            isRunning = false;
            startButton.Enabled = true;
            stopButton.Enabled = false;
            AddText("Stopping macro.");
        }

        private void clearLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            logTextBox.Text = "";
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cancellationTokenSource != null)
            {
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                cancellationTokenSource = null;
            }
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }
}

I created a program to find an image, compare it with the game window, and click on a random position of the image found in the window. It works fine up to this point, but there are too many error messages being displayed. I didn't encounter any errors on my computer, but my friend's computer showed error messages. I want to fix this issue.
Also, I would appreciate it if you could let me know if there are any strange contents in the code.

Look at this link that also describes issues with Mat - https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/540
I think you should call gc.Collect() manually ? Please write an answer to your own post if this helps to help other developers in future
